# MeteorJS camera preview with picture in transparency

Tags: javascript, mobile, meteor

I have to develop a mobile app, that shows the camera preview and an image in transparency at the same time, something like a very simple augmented reality.

I would like to use MeteorJS. Is it possible to accomplish the goal with this framework?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I see, basically Meteor has nothing to with your requirements. If you can do this with vanilla JS, you can do it with Meteor.

Comment: I can't understand :) Vanilla JS is nor for mobile app.
I would like to develop mobile app with MeteorJS and those requirements...

Comment: I meant that meteor is a "just" a js framework, if you can handle the camera input from JavaScript, you can meet your requirements with Meteor too

Comment: Ok. I got it :) the problem is that i don't have to save the camera input, but just to show it to the user, together with an other image from the app in transparency... i don't know how to get it.